# Verify shading in sbt-assembly IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, sbt-assembly

I'm trying to use GeoIP2 v2.10.0 Java API (https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-java) with Apache Spark v2.2.0, Scala 2.11.8. The problem is, Apache Spark has jackson-databind artifact v2.6.5 in it's pom file where as the GeoIP2 requires a miniumum version of jackson-databind 2.9.2. Hence, I'm trying to shade the associated libraries using `sbt-assembly`. I'm using `spark-submit` command on AWS-EMR, but I keep getting the following dependency error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode.<init>(Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/JsonNodeFactory;Ljava/util/List;)V at com.maxmind.db.Decoder.decodeArray(Decoder.java:272)
```

The above exception occurs mainly because jackson-databind v2.6.5 is being pulled from Spark rather than using 2.9.2. Can anyone tell me whether I'm doing the shading process correctly or if I'm missing anything? How do I verify whether the `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.*` is actually shaded to `shaded.jackson.core.*` in IntelliJ? I've tried to use the `sbt-dependencyTree` plugin, but shows me just the dependency as `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.*`.

The following is my `build.sbt` file:

```
    name := "Sessionization"
    version := "0.1"
    scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

    assemblyShadeRules in assembly := Seq(ShadeRule.rename("com.fasterxml.jackson.core.**" -> "shaded.jackson.core.@1").inAll
      //.inLibrary("com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.9.2")
      //.inLibrary("com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % "2.9.2")
      //.inLibrary("com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-annotations" % "2.9.0")
      //.inProject
)

    // Have to use "provided" because of some deduplicate error in merging many same-name class files.
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq("com.maxmind.geoip2" % "geoip2" % "2.10.0", //"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.2.0" % "provided",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.2.0" % "provided"
  //"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.2.0" excludeAll( ExclusionRule(organization="com.fasterxml.jackson.core")),
  //"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.2.0" excludeAll( ExclusionRule(organization="com.fasterxml.jackson.core"))
    )
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'll be honest, I have never used the assembly shade rules but have you tried either of these methods:

1. un-comment your exclusion rule attempt and replace the exclusion rule with `ExclusionRule(organization = "*", name = "jackson-core")`
2. Add a merge strategy to the bottom of your build.sbt. Something along the lines of:

   `assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
    case x if x.contains("decodeArray") => MergeStrategy.deduplicate
    case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
    case x => MergeStrategy.first
   }`

If you are still having problems then another useful thing to do is add  `conflictManager := ConflictManager.strict` to your build.sbt to identify conflicts.